# Python regex - find patterns in a file and put them in a list

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex to find all the matched patterns in a BibTex file. The file looks like this:

```
bib_file = """
@article{Fu_2007_ssr,
doi = {10.1016/j.surfrep.2007.07.001}
}

@article{Shibuya_2007_apl,
 doi = {10.1063/1.2816907}
}
"""
```

My goal is to find all the matched patterns with is from `@article` to `}` and put these patterns into a list. So my final list will be like this:

```
['@article{Fu_2007_ssr,\n  doi = {10.1016/j.surfrep.2007.07.001}\n   }',
 '@article{Shibuya_2007_apl,\n  doi = {10.1063/1.2816907}\n    }']
```

Currently, I have my code:

```
    rx_sequence = re.compile(r'(@article(.*)}\n)', re.DOTALL)
    article = rx_sequence.search(bib_file).group(1)
```

But the `article` is a string, how can I find each matched pattern and append it to a list?

Comment: `articles= list(rx_sequence.finditer(bib_file))`?

Comment: @Rawing Just tried that. Doesn't seem to work though

Comment: Why not use a Python [`bibtexparser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bibtexparser/0.6.2)?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: Thanks for letting me know this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match all these articles with

```
r"(@article.*?\n[ \t]*}[ \t]*)(?:\n|$)"
```

(to be used with `re.DOTALL` modifier for the `.` to match any char incl. a newline). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pO5hP6/2)

**Pattern details**:

- `(@article.*?\n[ \t]*}[ \t]*)` - Group 1 capturing a sequence of:

  - `@article` - a literal text `@article`
  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible, up to the first...
  - `\n[ \t]*}[ \t]*` - newline, followed with 0+ spaces/tabs, `}` and again 0+ spaces/tabs and...
- `(?:\n|$)` - either a newline (`\n`) or end of string (`$`).

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/ezGSJa):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(@article.*?\n[ \t]*}[ \t]*)(?:\n|$)', re.DOTALL)
s = "@article{Fu_2007_ssr,\ndoi = {10.1016/j.surfrep.2007.07.001}\n}\n\n@article{Shibuya_2007_apl,\n doi = {10.1063/1.2816907}\n}"
print(p.findall(s))
# => ['@article{Fu_2007_ssr,\ndoi = {10.1016/j.surfrep.2007.07.001}\n}',
#     '@article{Shibuya_2007_apl,\n doi = {10.1063/1.2816907}\n}']
```

Note that unrolling the pattern as

```
@article.*(?:\n(?![ \t]*}[ \t]*(?:\n|$)).*)*\s*}
```

will make it more robust. See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pO5hP6/4) and a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/edW2nN) (this regex does not require a `re.DOTALL` modifier).

Comment: See the unrolled version - it should not be used with `re.DOTALL` modifier, and will be more efficient.

Comment: Your code works. So `re.findall` will automatically put the matched patterns into a list?

Comment: Yes, `re.findall` puts either the matches (if no capturing groups are defined in the pattern), or the captured values (as list of tuples) if capture groups are defined.

Comment: It turns out `r'(@article.*?\n[ \t]*})'` also works in my case. Do you think it is robust enough?

Comment: I think you are using it with a `re.DOTALL`. The lazy dot matching pattern is not that efficient as an unrolled pattern, since the unrolled pattern is grabbing parts of string in chunks, and the `.*?` expands at each location in the string. If you compare it with the first pattern, it is less precise since it does not check if the trailing `}` is the only character on the line (my patterns check that).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use [`bibtexparser`](https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.2/) which saves you all the trouble:

```
>>> import bibtexparser
>>> bib_file = """
... @article{Fu_2007_ssr,
... doi = {10.1016/j.surfrep.2007.07.001}
... }
...
... @article{Shibuya_2007_apl,
...  doi = {10.1063/1.2816907}
... }
... """
>>> b = bibtexparser.loads(bib_file)
>>> b.entries
[{'ENTRYTYPE': 'article', 'ID': 'Fu_2007_ssr', 'doi': '10.1016/j.surfrep.2007.07.001'}, {'ENTRYTYPE': 'article', 'ID': 'Shibuya_2007_apl', 'doi': '10.1063/1.2816907'}]
```

There, you have a list containing the items from the bib file properly splitted and mapped to their bib titles.

Comment: However, the expected output is different from what OP needs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I figure they'll end up needing to split the contents of `article` again maybe with another regex. This library already deals with that

Comment: It is not a list, it's a dictionary, which lacks any information about the order of the fields.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning That's a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary appearing in the order from the text.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye That's what I meant. Each dictionary lacks information about the order of the fields.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Dictionaries in Python are not ordered.